# My css transition doesn't work when I add the <html> tags

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

When I add `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the top of my document, this transition doesn't work anymore. Why?

This works (in Chrome and Microsoft Edge):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .container{
            width: 400px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            background-color: #9FC;
        }
        .gradBox {
            width: 300px;
            height: 100px;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            border-top-left-radius: 15px;
            border-top-right-radius: 15px;
            -webkit-transition: width 1s;
            transition: width 1s;
        }
        .gradBox:hover {
            width: 400;
        }
        #grad1 {
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #F00 1%, #FF0 25%, #0F0 50%, #0FF 75%, #00F 100%)
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="gradBox" id="grad1">    
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This does not work in either:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    ... (the rest of the markup is identical)
```

Comment: Both seem to work just fine for me.

Comment: both code samples are the same?

Comment: @since095: The second example is using HTML5

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` is the HTML5 doctype. Hence the browser interprets the transition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to declare the unit on the width on hover:

```
.gradBox:hover {
  width: 400px;
}
```

You were using pixels in the initial css declaration so it will be used on hover as well. I don't know if it's a typo in your question or where but it does not work without the unit on either case so I can't really tell you why the other example would be working and the other not.

Comment: Good greif... How did I miss that! I spent the best part of an hour trying to figure out what was wrong.

Comment: Heh, happens to the best of us. Sometimes the minor mistakes are good at hide and seek ;)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing pixels in the hover section